# How can i show large selected item names on texts caption of dropdowncheckboxes in asp.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

In my web application, i have many dropdowncheckboxes but i need to display what i select all the items i need to show on the dropdowncheckboxes of the texts caption box.when i select small items names it shows perfectly.It will not show properly by selecting the large item names on texts caption box. i want to show large item names properly. when i select that large items and select by mouse those names and move arrows buttons (keyboard keys) on texts caption of dropdowncheckboxes it will show all the names without change the dropdowncheckboxes width is it possible to do.

how can i do this can anyone please help me
Thank you

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEIhq.png)

Comment: share your html and css code.

Comment: i updated my code. Can you see once. Thank you

Comment: can you show me expected and current output image?

Comment: I updated my images link below with the caption "image description here". Can you see once. I hope you can understand those images. thank you

Comment: <Style SelectBoxWidth="330" DropDownBoxBoxWidth="200" />

Comment: I updated your code into my application. when i select all the items It shows two names only and i select all names on that time i need to increase width it is not possible to increasing width all the time. Can you tell me any another way to do this.Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123666/discussion-between-jeetdaloneboy-and-shiv).

Comment: I tried it's not working